# How do I use more than one generic type?

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I know that doing the following method will return me T.

```
 public static T SomeMethod<T>(string meh, T paramName)
 {  
    return T;
 }

/// I have come to a situation that I am returning a different type 
/// I have the following mind:
public static T SomeMethod<T>(U paramName)
 {  
     return T;
 }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You need both type parameters in the method declaration: `SomeMethod<T,U>`. Of course, `return T;` is still not valid, I assume that's a placeholder.

Comment: In order to use a generic type, it has to be a generic type argument of the generic method (or class). So if you want to use `U` as a type argument with `SomeMethod`, you need to add it as an argument: `SomeMethod<T, U>`.

Comment: This won't compile `return T;` is not valid syntax because `T` is a type and not a value. It would be like typing `return int;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have multiple generics in one type:

```
public static T SomeMethod<T, U>(U paramName)
 {  
     return T;
 }
```

To use it:

```
string myString = SomeMethod<string,int>(3);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was exactly what I was looking for. ^_^

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 2):

This is how you do a conversion between types

```
class Program
{
    public static T SomeMethod<T>(T paramName)
    {
        return paramName;
    }
    public static U SomeMethod<T, U>(T paramName, Func<T,U> convert)
    {
        return convert(paramName);
    }


    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var A=SomeMethod(1033);
        // A = 1033
        var B=SomeMethod(1033, (x) => x.ToString());
        // B = "1033"
    }
}
```